# Saving all EditText texts displayed in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-edittext

My idea is to create a table where I can store my players scores in different activities.

I thought creating a GridView which contains an EditText so I can change values dynamically. Looking for in the web I found some source codes which I modified. I got my purpose (create a GridView with an EditText inside) however now I'm not able to retrieve the data (numbers in this case) stored in the EditTexts.

Do you know how could I do it?

Thanks in advance,

**This is my Adapter**:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import

android.widget.EditText;

public class AdaptadorResultados extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Activity context;
       
    AdaptadorResultados(Activity context,String[] datos) {
    super(context, R.layout.resultados, datos);
    this.context = context;
    }
   
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resultados, null);
        
        final EditText txtCelda =(EditText)item.findViewById(R.id.txtCelda2);
        txtCelda.setText(this.getItem(position).toString());

return(item);
}
```

**This the xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/txtCelda2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    ></EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

#### Solved

Finally I got it changing the source code of the adaptor. I post it here in case someone has the same problem:

```
public class AdaptadorEditText extends BaseAdapter{

private Context myContext;
private String[]nombres;
private EditText[] myCells;

public AdaptadorEditText(Context c, String[] nombres, int num){

    myContext=c;
    this.nombres=nombres;
    myCells=new EditText[nombres.length*num];
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return nombres.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return myCells[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    EditText cell;
      if (myCells[position] == null)
         {
       cell = myCells[position] = new EditText(myContext);
       cell.setText(nombres[position]);
            }
         else
         {
          cell = myCells[position];
         }
         return cell;
     }
```

Comment: Hey fRubio, could we have a little more information? Are you successfully putting your text in those edit texts already? and at which point would you like to get the text out the edittext? :)

Comment: I'm a football coach so I want to create an app to make my job easier. I want to create a table: 1st row for the name of the activities I will measure, 1st column with the names of my players and the rest of the cells should contain the results they score. I've created a GridView with EditText inside to insert the results. My problem know is that I want to getTex() from the EditText to store them in a data base.However, I don know how to do it. Is it usefull or do you want another kind of information, Losin'Me?

Comment: Are you clicking an overall "save" button or would you like it to save once you finished editing the text?

Comment: Yes. I can see the EditText and I'm able to write on them. The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the new text inserted. if i do a getItem(position) it gives me nothing or old text(previously inserted when the gridview is created)

Comment: I would like to click an overall button and save all the information. However if that is complicated, saving it after finishing editing text would be OK

Comment: Okay; with this additional information people should get what you wish to achieve :)